# Input data from serial port to Excel

Tags: excel, serial-port, arduino

I've built an interface from a digital Caliper to an Arduino board.
The Arduino sends the readings from the caliper to the computer via Serial port.

The data sent over the serial port is of course fully customizable.

I now want an option that when a certain command comes over the serial port (For instance generated by a button press in the caliper) the data of the caliper will be inputed into the current Cell in Excel and the tab key pressed in order to move to the next cell.

I wanted to know what is your recommended solution? What programming language? How to send the data to Excel? How to emulate the Tab key? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually used the following solution:
Downloaded and installed scaleProgrammer.com Rs-232 Monitor (for free) and using it translated the incoming serial incoming data to keyboard input.

To the incoming serial data I added the TAB key at the end of every transmition, which aids in working in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your reqquirement, but I hope you can use an Ethernet shield and do some PHP coding to store your output in CSV format, which later you can read using the Excel.

Please give a proper description of your requirement so you can get some good answer. Any link/pics of you tool will work.

You can try [php-serial](http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/).

Comment: As I wrote (quite clearly, in my opinion) in the third paragraph, I wan t to input data cell by cell real-time and on demand. I even explained about the connected device, a digital caliper. I'm sorry but your answer was not very helpfull.

Comment: So you need it to display real time in the excle sheet is that you requirement or display it in a web browser will work?